# Rancher Docker container UI unreacheable on 8080 port

Tags: docker, orchestration, rancher

I have checked before running container port with `netstat -anp | grep 8080.*LISTEN`, its output was empty.
After starting `Rancher` with `docker run -d --restart=always -p 8080:8080 rancher/server` port 8080 isn't showing GUI, connection unsuccessful.

Comment: what does a `$netcat 127.0.0.1 8080` outputs?

Comment: Here is running container: `af4e96802e90        rancher/server      "/usr/bin/s6-svscan /"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   big_golick`

Comment: What does "Nothing." mean? Waiting for a time-out? An error message such as `unable to connect to address 127.0.0.1, service 8080`? Is your Rancher service really running? Try a `docker exec af4e96802e90 bash -c "ps aux"` to see if you server is running, check also the logs with `docker logs af4e96802e90`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the speed of the computer and storage starting up can take a couple minutes, especially on the first start where it goes through all the database migrations.  Also make sure you're running on a host/VM with at least 1GB of RAM.

When it's done starting up the log will say

> 08:20:37.213 [main] INFO  ConsoleStatus - [DONE ] [40787ms] Startup Succeeded, Listening on port 8081
>   time="2015-11-20T08:20:38Z" level=info msg="Starting websocket proxy. Listening on [:8080], Proxying to cattle API at [localhost:8081], Monitoring parent pid [10]."